# MERN Stack Error: how to resolve "Cannot GET /" error when running backend server?

Tags: mongodb, express, heroku, mern

I know there are loads of posts on stack overflow about this issue. However, I can't find the solution to this problem when I try what is suggested on the other posts and some answers I don't find them very clear. That's why, I thought it useful to ask this question by emphasizing where my mistake is. So I am currently working on the backend of my MERN application, when I run my server I get the following message in my [terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6taWf.png)  .Personally I am a beginner and I was expecting it to tell me that everything went successfully and it automatically opens a tab for me on my browser. When I manually open the tab at the specified address i.e.: `http://localhost:5000/`, I get the error `Cannot GET /` I don't even know what it means. Here are the contents of my files:

**config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  PORT: process.env.PORT || 4000,
  MONGODB_URI: process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost:27017/facebook_clone",
  JWT_SECRET: process.env.JWT_SECRET || "itssecret",
  JWT_EXP: process.env.JWT_EXPIRE || '10h',
  ADMIN_EMAIL: process.env.ADMIN_EMAIL || "admin@gmail.com",
  ADMIN_PASSWORD: process.env.ADMIN_PASSWORD || "admin@123",
}
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
require("dotenv").config()
const app = express()
const http = require('http')
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)

const UserRoutes = require('./routes/User')
const AuthRoutes = require('./routes/Auth')
const PostRoutes = require('./routes/Post')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
const {MONGODB_URI} = require("./config")

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  io.req = req
  req.io = io
  next()
})

app.use('/api/auth', AuthRoutes)
app.use('/api/user', UserRoutes)
app.use('/api/post', PostRoutes)

require('./socket')(io)

mongoose
  .connect(MONGODB_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('database connected')
    server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server started on port ${PORT}`))
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon index.js",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "heroku": "^7.60.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.7.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.7",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "socket.io": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

I even tried to change the port number from 4000 to 5000 in my config.js file but without success. And so I hope more experienced members of the community can help me. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably the reason is that you did not specify that route in your app in your routes for example app.use("/"), otherwise in your browser URL if you navigate to one of the routes below you'll get a result:
HTTP://localhost:5000/api/auth
HTTP://localhost:5000/api/user
HTTP://localhost:5000/api/post

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean because when I look at my index.js file, I did specify the routes that led to such content and gave the structure of my url unless it was me who don't understand what you mean not there, please can you show me some sample code to clear me up and help me better understand what you mean

Comment: I meant the route that leads to ("/") doesn't exist in your app routes, because by default when you start your server it's opening on HTTP://localhost:3000 by default, which means the app is trying to render something from the ("/") route, but the route doesn't exist .
add this line to your index and you'll understand, app.use("/",()=>{console.log("hello from / route"}) ;

Comment: It works but whenever I try to access localhost:5000 on my browser no new tab is opened but just a message is written in console line and you will need to lay out your code better there are formats for the code even in comments too, your line of code has an error because a parenthesis is missing.